# Xcode 4 Version editor left-to-right

Tags: version-control, xcode4

Right now, Xcode 4's version editor shows my local changes on the left and the latest revision on the right.  It seems more logical to have it reversed, so that the later point in time (my local changes) are on the right.  Is there a setting somewhere for this?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can manually select the version shown in each below. That's probably a pain though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no option except as "webjprgm" described - manually switching them by selecting versions. I believe you'll have to do this each time, so it's not really going to satisfy you.

I feel the same way about the Assistant showing the counterparts. I'd always had a split screen with .h on top and .m on bottom as it made logical sense to me (there's a reason it's called a "header"). It bugs me to no end but there's no option for "assistant editors on top".

File an enhancement request at http://bugreporter.apple.com